# Check if a catalog pricerule is active

Tags: magento-1.9, php, price-rules

How do i programmatically check if a catalog pricerule is active or not?

I have tried loading collection like this, where 13 is ID of the catalog rule:

```
$catalog_rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(13);
```

And then use

```
if (!empty($catalog_rule)) {
    echo 'foo';
}
```

This always returns true nomatter if rule is active or not.

How do i check if catalog price rule is not empty and is active?

Comment: Try to make: Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(13)->getIsActive();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php

```
* @method int getIsActive()
```

Try

```
$catalog_rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(13);

if ($catalog_rule->getIsActive()) {
    echo 'foo';
}
```